# Chrome does not load videos

Tags: google, video

This problem is very weird for it has never happened until now. Whenever I want to play a video in chrome it starts to load the video after which it stops and shows the play button again but it does not function when tapped and this happens for every video. What is causing this?

Comment: What device do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the browser's cache in the browser's settings will do the trick. I hope it helps

Comment: Is this a guess, or a known solution? Any background on why that should help? What does playing a video have to do with browser *history?*

Comment: Chrome browser by default stores data of websites in cache which affects the way a page load. Clearing the *history and cache* will allow the browser to freshly load the website's content fixing such issues. I had similar problem where i had internet connection but the error "site couldn't be reached".

Comment: OK, I had that idea concerning *cache* as well. But why *history?* Wouldn't it be sufficient to go to *Settings › Apps*, navigate to the browser, and "clear cache" from there? One might not want to lose the history in some situations.

Comment: Well, you're right about the history. Let me reframe the answer. Thanks

Comment: Tried but didn't work. I cleared cache the first time, second time I deleted stored data but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Yea I had the same problem, assumed it's some chrome bug and downloaded chrome canary. Try that, it would be mentioned that it's an unstable version but it works better.